# Getting "no space left on devide" when installing app from eclipse/adb to LG Optimus Hub

Tags: android

Getting this error while running debug:

```
[2012-07-25 14:53:49 - myprogram] Uploading myprogram.apk onto device '80A358688043073949'
[2012-07-25 14:54:12 - myprogram] Failed to install myprogram.apk on device '80A358688043073949': No space left on device
[2012-07-25 14:54:12 - myprogram] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device
```

Error pops up when this app was already installed on the smartphone (Debug - fix smth - Debug again)
Only manually uninstalling previous app helps.

I have specified android:installLocation="preferExternal" in my AndroidManifest, but that didn't help (SD card has huge amount of free space)

Answer (score 1):

Even you speical external only, the apk will use internal storage to save data/dalvik cache, etc, you can use link2SD, or just uninstall some other unused apks.

Comment: Is there a way to make adb automatically uninstall app with same id prior to installing debugged app?